# debian debuild wheezy perl module packaging

Tags: perl, debian, perl-module, deb

I'm building debian packages out of perl module distributions

Everything is fine I think but I'm a little confused about the tgz-check

I had configured it out (--no-tgz-check) but now I have original builds to use I added it back in. However I couldn't see that it did anything. My module code has certainly change. Is this unnecessary for my needs - The  packages are going nowhere near a public repository

And also what is it for?

Thanks for any insights
Jeremy